# Can anyone please explain the implementation of console.count?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var user = "";

function greet() {
 console.count();
 return "hi " + user;
}

user = "bob";
greet();
user = "alice";
greet();
greet();
console.count();
```

In the above example the console shows 1, 2, 3 and then 1 . 
How does console.count works ? Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: Is explained in the MDN docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/count   Is a count of each instance being called

Comment: Sorry, I mean its implementation, not functionality.

Comment: @LakshmipriyaMukundan It could look at the stack trace, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find an answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/count

Briefly:

> This function logs the number of times that this particular call to
>   `count()` has been called. This function takes an optional argument
>   `label`.
>
> If `label` is supplied, this function logs the number of times
>   `count()` has been called with that particular `label`.
>
> If `label` is omitted, the function logs the number of times `count()`
>   has been called **at this particular line**.

That's why you are getting different results because 3 times it is called inside the function, let's say it is line number 4, and one time it is called at another line (the last line in your script).

Comment: Sorry , I mean its implementation.

Comment: I guess it depends on the browser. Each browser has its own JS engine I suppose and the implementation may vary, and it's probably some native stuff that you cannot find easily.

Comment: and your question was How does console.count works ? So that is basically what my answer was about ))

Answer (score 0):

You called the greet() function 3 time in a row, that's why its print 1 2 3. but out side the function console.count() execute 1 time, that's why it's print 1.